# How to populate an array with information from JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Basically I'm trying to add information from a JSON file into my array, however the information returns as 'undefined' because nothing is actually created in my array. 
Here is the contents of the JSON file:

```
   "histogram": [ 
      {  
         "type": "Comedy",
         "count": 4
      },
      {  
         "type": "Action",
         "count": 5
      },
      {  
         "type": "Romance",
         "count": 6
      },
      {  
         "type": "Drama",
         "count": 1
      },
      {  
         "type": "SciFi",
         "count": 4
      }
   ]
}
```

The code I have been using so far uses the push() function to add information however it does not seem to correctly add the information. Here is the code:

```
let movies;
function preload() {
movies = loadJSON('movies.json');
}

count = [];

var c0 = movies.histogram[0].count;
count.push(c0);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks :)

Comment: You're never calling your `preload` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `preload` so that `movies` is populated with data:

```
count = [];
preload();
```

However, there is all probability that `loadJSON` is an asynchronous operation - as such, you will need to modify your code like so:

```
async function preload() {
  let data = await loadJSON("movies.json");
  movies = data;
}

count = [];
(async () => {
  preload();
  var c0 = movies.histogram[0].count;
  count.push(c0);
})();
```

The `async` IIFE is just a quick way of calling an asynchronous function correctly.